# How to get actual document from Clio API?

Tags: clio-api

I want to create a webhook that is notified whenever a document is uploaded or changed, so that I can analyze that document for the user.

I have looked at the APIs for documents, but I don't see how to get the actual document itself.

I'm new to the API and probably missing something, but...how do you download a document after it has been uploaded to Clio?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API Documentation](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#tag/Documents/operation/Document#download)
The API can download a document using the following address, using the ID that was provided from your webhook:

```
{BaseURL}/documents/{id}/download.json
```